# why does dropbox keep syncing when nothing is changing?

Tags: macos, sync, dropbox

I've got a particularly large file (about 500MB) that frequently changes, one one of the machines that sync together isn't fast enough at times to keep up - it doesn't finish synching before another (small) change comes in, so it immediately starts resyncing.   So for the past several months I have turned off syncing on this machine.

This evening I decided to re-enable it, as I have reduced the frequency at which the file updates to twice per day. However, what I am seeing is, Dropbox still exhibits the behavior where it counts down the time until the sync is done (generally about 4 minutes), but then as soon as it reaches zero it does a bit of processing, and then indicates another sync is in progress.  No files are changing, so I am at a loss as to why it doesn't stop syncing.  None of the other machines that sync together have any activity.

Could Dropbox be trying to sync all the backup copies or something?  The disk usage in the cache directory doesn't exactly support this (cache usage seems to have dropped quite a bit since I began), but I don't know how else to explain why it keeps trying to resync a couple files.

Comment: Exit of Dropbox on both machines and restart it. Does that stop the unnecessary syncing?

Comment: @sunk818 The machine that was doing the unnecessary syncing was rebooted, which necessarily stopped Dropbox before restarting it.  I have not tried restarting it on all my other machines.  Should I try restarting it just on any machines on the LANs or all linked boxes regardless of location?

Comment: One at a time and observe each machine. One client maybe perpetuating the others...